# Single word for "able to blend in"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing about an analogy that is made in a text that I am reading between a substance that blends in to the point of being incapable of being identified as a distinct object (like a certain type of flour into another, when they are mixed) and an object that remains a distinct object, even when blended with other like objects (like, say, a marble).

Is there a single word for the type of substance that blends (the flour)? It's not exactly dissoluble (flour doesn't dissolve)...

The sentence is:

> Whether the item is _____ is one of the factors that determines whether it corrupts the mass into which it is blended.

Comment: You could try ***homogenizable***.  But I'd try rewriting to use another form of the word if possible.

Comment: *Corrupts the mass*? This is something that won't happen until it's fully mixed, blended, incorporated, or what have you?

Comment: [Miscible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscibility) comes close.

Comment: It’s been a few days now, and there’re no another in coming answer. Trying editing some contexts in your question will make your question active again. And if there was a correct answer for your question, please marked an answer as correct (the green check image) on It.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/camouflageable

Answer (score 1):

**[Miscible](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/miscible)**: from chemistry

> Definition of miscible
>   : capable of being mixed specifically : capable of mixing in any ratio without separation of two phases

Might sound a little odd in a social context, but it fulfills your, apparently multiple-liquid, situation.

Answer (score 0):

Your example sentence suggests completion with descriptive word meaning a state that would lend itself to corruption of the greater mass. Three possible solutions might be **inextricable** or **irretrievable** or simply **lost**. You could also use *extricable*, *retrievable*, or *salvageable* to the same end in the uncorrupting sense.

> Whether the item is ***irretrievable*** is one of the factors that
>   determines whether it corrupts the mass into which it is blended.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/inextricable

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/irretrievable

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/lost

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/salvageable

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense in this context, but doesn't describe the quality that the text I'm translating is defining.

Answer (score 0):

Would the words **coalesced** or **amalgamated** describe the quality of your textual translation? If not, then perhaps this thesaurus link might be of help.

https://www.powerthesaurus.org/coalesce

**Usage example**

Whether the item is **coalesced** is one of the factors that determines whether it corrupts the mass into which it is blended.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/coalesce

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/amalgamate

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could "borrow" a term from the illicit drug world. and say whether it can be used to **"cut"** the other substance.

*Whether the item is **a cutting agent** is one of the factors...*

> A **cutting agent** is a chemical used to "cut" (dilute) recreational drugs with something less expensive than the drug itself.
> [...]
> Cocaine has been cut with various substances ranging from flour and powdered milk to ground drywall and other common, easily obtainable substances.
> [...]
> When choosing a cutting agent, the drug manufacturer or dealer would ideally attempt to find a chemical that is inexpensive, easy to obtain, relatively non-toxic, and mimics the physical attributes of the drug to be adulterated.
>
> — https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_agent

Answer (score 0):

From [Meriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mutable#examples)

mutable adjective
mu·​ta·​ble | \ˈmyü-tə-bəl  \
Definition of mutable 
1 : prone to change : INCONSTANT
mutable opinions
2a : capable of change or of being changed
mutable laws
b : capable of or liable to mutation
mutable vowels
a mutable gene

Examples of mutable in a Sentence
 the government's mutable economic policies
 a politician with very mutable positions on all the issues

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, in your sentence "distinguishable", "recognisable" and "discernible" would work.

> Whether the item is distinguishable is one of the factors that determines whether it corrupts the mass into which it is blended.
>
> Whether the item is recognisable is one of the factors that determines whether it corrupts the mass into which it is blended.
>
> Whether the item is discernible is one of the factors that determines whether it corrupts the mass into which it is blended.

Comment: This would be a worthwhile answer if you added some authoritative detail demonstrating why each of the words is suitable - for example, dictionary definitions with links to sources. You can add the detail using the [edit] link. For further guidance, see [answer].

Comment: While that works in this sentence, I need the opposite word to discuss what comes later. I need a word that means "not distinguishable, when blended."

Answer (score -2):

## **["blendable"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blendable)** becomes [a](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&geo=GB&q=%22blendable%22,%22disslove%22) word [now](https://www.google.co.th/search?ei=cF7EW52pDM2P9QPS8aRg&q=%22blendable%22&oq=%22blendable%22&gs_l=psy-ab.4...1017.2636.0.2762.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.VXfib9DfO20)

Comment: Blendable sounds more like "is capable of being blended, eg in a drinks blender".  So, for example a strawberry is blendable in the way that, say, a hammer isn't.